# Bernstein's theorem for non-finite measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Bernstein's theorem states the following:

> Let $g: [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty)$ be a smooth function. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> (a) $g$ is a completely monotone function, i.e. $(-1)^{n}g^{(n)}(x) \geq 0$ for all $n \geq 0$ and $x \geq 0$.
>
> (b) $g(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} d\mu(t)$ for some (unique) finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $[0, \infty)$.

I wonder if we can modify this theorem slightly to the functions on $(0, \infty)$ (exclude $0$) and allow non-finite measures. For example, we have $\frac{1}{x} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-tx} dt$, and the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is completely monotone on $(0, \infty)$, and the corresponding measure is $dt$, which is not finite.

Another example is $g(x) = 1 + e^{-x} + e^{-2x} + \cdots = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-x}}$, which is completely monotone on $(0, \infty)$ and a Laplace transform of the measure $\mu = \sum_{n \geq 0} \delta_{n}$, which is again not finite.

Comment: It seems clear that b) implies a) (with $x>0$) when $d\mu$ is a non-finite measure.  Good question. It probably requires understanding the proof of Bernstein's theorem.

Comment: this is theorem $12b$ chapter $4$ (p $161$ in my edition) in Widder's reference book  book The Laplace Transform and the proof is by applying the usual theorem to $f(x+\epsilon)$ and using the unicity of the measure $d\mu(\epsilon)$ so obtained to show that one extends the other if $\epsilon_1 <\epsilon_2$

Comment: @Conrad This is exactly what I wanted - thank you very much!!

Comment: happy to be of help